# Why does this INSERT statement require a SELECT grant?

Tags: mysql, permissions, amazon-aurora

I am running approximately the following SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO a_table
    (file_hash, p, c)
VALUES
    (%(hash)s, %(p)s, %(c)s)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    p = %(p)s,
    c = %(c)s
;
```

with these parameters, though I'm masking the values:

```
[parameters: {'hash': -, 'p': -, 'c': -}]
```

MySQL gives me the following error:

```
SELECT command denied to user 'our_user'@'10.1.1.2' for column 'p' in table 'a_table'"
```

Why?

(The nearest the manual seems to come to explaining this is,

> The `SELECT` privilege is also needed for other statements that read column values. For example, `SELECT` is needed for columns referenced on the right hand side of col_name=expr assignment in `UPDATE` statements

But we're not referencing that column (`p`) on the RHS of an assignment in our statement. We're not attempting to read that value *anywhere* here that I can see.)

The schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `a_table` (
  `file_hash` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `p` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_hash`),
  KEY `idx_p` (`p`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

(Edit: I'm also having some difficulty duplicating this outside my live environment; this is occurring on an AWS MySQL Aurora instance.)

Comment: It has to do a SELECT to work out if it's a duplicate key?

Comment: It is asking for SELECT on `p`, which isn't part of any key. (Ignore the `KEY` line in the schema; MySQL erroneously uses `KEY` to mean index.)

Comment: I have the same issue here with a linked server. Only with SELECT granted can other servers do an INSERT